# Why, when using bootstrap, are there no margins for dynamically generated form fields?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a simple form that permits the user to add an unlimited amount of additional rows.  The form is styled with bootstrap.  Why, when the fields are generated dynamically, are there no margins?

[image: picture of form fields]

**HTML:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
</head>
<body>

<div id="form">    
    <div class="form-inline">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for='originalInput'>Original Input</label>
            <input class='form-control' type='text' value='' name='originalInput'></input>
        </div>
         <div class="form-group">
            <label for='originalInput'>Original Input</label>
            <input class='form-control' type='text' value='' name='originalInput'></input>
        </div>
         <div class="form-group">
            <label for='originalInput'>Original Input</label>
            <input class='form-control' type='text' value='' name='originalInput'></input>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<button id="button">Add New Group</button>
<script src="jquery-2.1.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="example.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</body>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(function () {
    function createGroup(name) {
        var label = document.createElement("label");
        $label = $(label);
        $label.attr("for", name)
            .text(name);

        var input = document.createElement("input");
        $input = $(input);
        $input.addClass("form-control")
            .attr("type", "text")
            .attr("name", name);

        var validation = document.createElement("span");
        $validation = $(validation);
        $validation.addClass("field-validation-valid")
            .attr("data-valmsg-for", name)
            .attr("data-valmsg-replace", "true");

        var group = document.createElement("div");
        $group = $(group);
        $group.addClass("form-group")
            .append(label, input, validation);

        return group;
    }

    $("#button").click(
        function () {
            var newFormInline = document.createElement("div");
            $(newFormInline).append(createGroup("New Input"),
                    createGroup("New Input"),
                    createGroup("New Input"))
                .addClass("form-inline");

            $("#form").append(newFormInline);
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you checked how does the HTML look after you create the elements? Is the structure correct?

Comment: Yes, I checked.  Aside from the attribute order, the structure is identical.

Comment: Because your literal HTML has a carriage return, the inserted HTML from the javascript does not.

Comment: Proof -> http://jsfiddle.net/zs2ry5nn/

Comment: When I remove all of the carriage returns form the html, the spaces disappear.  Why would bootstrap insert spaces here?  How would minified html affect this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap makes any .form-group class display inline-block.  The browser inserts a space after any inline-block element with trailing white-space or carriage returns.  For the elements constructed with javascript, the returns aren't present, and, thus, the trailing space is not inserted.

This leaves three options:

1. Add the spaces to the new elements created with javascript
2. Remove the spaces from the original html and adjust the margins
3. Use a template

Chris Coyier eloquently describes the options for space removal in [this article](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/).

Adding the spaces to the javascript is as simple as throwing them into the jquery append method found in the click event:

```
 $("#button").click(
    function () {
        var newFormInline = document.createElement("div");
        $(newFormInline).append(createGroup("New Input"), " ",
                createGroup("New Input"), " ",
                createGroup("New Input"))
            .addClass("form-inline");

        $("#form").append(newFormInline);
});
```

And the append method where we append the form group's child elements:

```
var group = document.createElement("div");
    $group = $(group);
    $group.addClass("form-group")
        .append(label, " ", input," ", validation);
```

Template options: you can use a client side templating engine like underscore's, handlebars, etc., or a server side template that is retrieved via an ajax request.